# i want to write the dynamic script to get data from DBMS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

There are multiple records in db against single ID. I want to get only single value from duplicate data and single different value in next column against single ID. do i need to use the pivot or something else.

i am trying this on SQL server

```
select distinct (d.SetId), s.Description, sd.SourceValue, d.TargetValue, d.TargetEntityDetailCode,e.entitydisplayname,e.entitycode from P2P_ADRSet s
inner join P2P_ADRSourceDataMaster sd on sd.SourceCombinationId = s.SourceCombinationId
inner join P2P_ADRDataMaster d on d.SourceDataId = sd.SourceDataId and d.SetId = s.SetId
Inner join org_entitydetails e on e.Entitydetailcode = d.TargetEntityDetailCode
where sd.SourceValue in (249,66)
```

-- i want this source value which is 249 and 66 in different column. for now its showing in single column.

Comment: You need to pivot based on your ID

Comment: Can you please add some sample data?